# Add external data to Instance variable in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, mongoid

I have a query written in Mongoid

```
@result = User.find(:name=>"xxxxx").limit(5)
```

and I return the data in json as

```
render :json =>@result.to_json()
```

Now I want add the total number of user whose names are **xxxxx** into the `@result` variable. I have tried few thing but nothing worked ex

```
@new_result ={:result =>@result, :count=>@result.length}
```

and

```
render :json =>@new_result.to_json()
```

the output is

```
[{new_result:null,count:25}]
```

Basically I am able to get the count but I am not able to add that count to my @result. Is there a way to get this working.

Comment: It works for me. I can't see any problems.

Comment: I get an unexpected output   [{new_result:null,count:25}]

Comment: This works length={'count'=>@result.length}  ---  @new_result=@result<<length --- render :json =>(@new_result).to_json()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A gentle reminder:

```
All queries in Mongoid are Criteria, which is a chainable and lazily evaluated wrapper to a MongoDB dynamic query.
```

See: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#query_plus

Make sure to understand that Mongoid Criteria are lazily evaluated, otherwise it will cause you confusion
and cost you time, and more time ...

When I run your @result = User.find(:name=>"xxxxx").limit(5), I get a Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound exception,
this is with Mongoid 2.4.10.  Are you sure that your question is accurate?

I've changed it to User.where, and @result = User.find(:name=>"xxxxx").limit(5) is a Criteria,
not (yet) a User instance read from MongoDB.

The following test should help to make clear that due to lazy evaluation,
the DB query only occurs when it is needed, e.g., after method to_json and method length.
Also, tail your log, and note that each use of @result with a to_json or length method
results in a repeated DB query which is inefficient and probably not what you intended.
You can force an evaluation and fetch by using methods like Enumerable#to_a or Enumerable#each.

test/unit/user_test.db

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    User.delete_all
  end

  test "mongoid lazy eval" do
    User.create(name: 'xxxxx')
    assert_equal(1, User.count)
    puts "User.all.to_a: #{User.all.to_a.inspect}"
    assert_raises Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound do
      @result = User.find(:name=>"xxxxx").limit(5)
    end
    puts "@result = User.find(:name=>\"xxxxx\").limit(5); @result: #{@result.inspect}"
    @result = User.where(:name=>"xxxxx").limit(5)
    puts "@result = User.where(:name=>\"xxxxx\").limit(5); @result.class: #{@result.class}"
    puts "@result.to_json: #{@result.to_json}"
    puts "@result.length: #{@result.length}"
    @new_result ={:result =>@result, :count=>@result.length}
    puts "@new_result: #{@new_result.inspect}"
    puts "@new_result.to_json: #{@new_result.to_json}"
  end
end
```

test output

```
Run options: --name=test_mongoid_lazy_eval

# Running tests:

User.all.to_a: [#<User _id: 4fca03e7e4d30b1e42000001, _type: nil, name: "xxxxx">]
@result = User.find(:name=>"xxxxx").limit(5); @result: nil
@result = User.where(:name=>"xxxxx").limit(5); @result.class: Mongoid::Criteria
@result.to_json: [{"_id":"4fca03e7e4d30b1e42000001","name":"xxxxx"}]
@result.length: 1
@new_result: {:result=>#<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {:name=>"xxxxx"},
  options:  {:limit=>5},
  class:    User,
  embedded: false>
, :count=>1}
@new_result.to_json: {"result":[{"_id":"4fca03e7e4d30b1e42000001","name":"xxxxx"}],"count":1}
.

Finished tests in 0.038161s, 26.2048 tests/s, 52.4095 assertions/s.

1 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```